# how can I add line number in textwrangler search and replace?

Tags: replace, textwrangler

So I have a big text file with a string in the middle that looks like "id:"
and I would like to add the line number as id value. So ideally I would 
be search and replacing something like:

Search for:

```
"id:
```

replace with:

```
"id:<line number>
```

Is that possible with Textwrangler?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, for Linux and macOS, I put the following script in Textwrangler's  "Text Filters" directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/awk '/^"id:$/ {print $0 NR; next} {print}'
```

You can then run the filter from the 'Text/ Apply Text Filter...' menu.